# Using subset in R but got one particular subset with 0 rows

Tags: r

I used R to subset a data set D (in CSV format) but D3 always contains 0 rows "**<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)**." I checked the data set and did not find any missing values. What could be the problem with my data set? Thanks!

```
D <- read.csv(file="C:\\...\\D.csv", header = T, sep = ",")

D1 <- subset(D, Season == "Spring")
D2 <- subset(D, Season == "Summer")
D3 <- subset(D, Season == "Fall")

D3
[1] Cost
[2] Gender                                     
[3] Participant                                 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

names(D)
[1] "Cost"
[2] "Gender"                                     
[3] "Participant"                                    

unique(B$Season)
[1] Spring       Summer    Fall            
3 Levels: Fall Spring Summer
```

I created a new data set containing only D3 (in CSV format), and the problem was gone. However, that was not an efficient solution.

Thanks everyone for all your suggestions! I just retyped every "Fall" in my original CSV data set, which somehow worked.

Comment: Typing D3 gives only the variable names.

Comment: Can you show us the result of `names(D)` and then (assuming `Season` is one of the fields in `D`) the result of `unique(D$Season)`? That should show you directly if `"Fall"` is one of the values of `D$Season`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you're taking a `subset`, you should check the logical statement you're using. If your data frame is relatively small ( < 25 rows or so), then run:

```
D$Season == "Fall"
```

That will give you a vector like:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Or even:

```
which(D$Season == "Fall")

[1] 1 2 6
```

This is telling you which `rows` subset will select.

If you have a huge data frame, just do:

```
table(D$Season == "Fall")
```

This will tell you how many rows have the value `Fall`. I am willing do bet if you run `table(D$Season == "Fall")` you will see that all results come up `FALSE`

Comment: You got it; it gave me all FALSE's. Why did my D1 and D2 work fine with "subset?"

Comment: `subset` worked fine every time. The issue is that there are no values where `Season` is `Fall` in D.

Comment: How can I fix this problem in my original CSV data set?

Comment: What exactly is "the problem"?

Comment: By retyping every "Fall" in my data set, the problem was gone somehow. Thanks!